# how to avoid flash install?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, web

i have not used any flash contents in my web page, 
i have disabled flash plugin of my browser, i don't want my webpages to use the flash,and there are no flash contents in my page,whenever i refresh my page ,i get a popup window on the top of the page, to download flash ..
how to avoid these ?

i have tried the following code,

```
 function disable_flash_uploader() 
    {
   return false;
    }

add_filter( 'flash_uploader', 'disable_flash_uploader', 1 );
```

but not working..
please suggest me!

Comment: Flash player sometimes needed in your system to play videos or animations etc. Some webpage also automatically popup like install flash player and most of them are virus infected.

Comment: Disable all plugins and swap to a default theme, does it still happens?

Comment: @brasofilo, ya disabled all plugins, but still in same stage.